# Random Text Array + Fade on Interval + Shuffle

Tags: jquery

I have an array of text that comes in over a set interval with a fade and is randomized ([see my website](http://zbettendorf.com)). The problem being that I want the array to shuffle, so that none of the text repeats until all of the array has cycled through. I tried adding `textArray.shuffle();` directly after the array (among multiple other solutions), but so far the shuffle has either had no effect or kills the script entirely.

Here is the entirety of my script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var textArray = [
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I\'m allergic to pineapples, gum, and woolly bear caterpillars. And Comic Sans.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I love Apple products.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I have touched the North, East, West, and South coasts of the USA.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I\'m a designer.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I lived in Minnesota for 20 years. I\'ve lived in Ohio for 2 and a half.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. Two of my favorite artists are Shepard Fairey and Banksy.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. Bettendorf (my last name) is also the name of one of the Quad Cities.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. My high school graduating class consisted of just 36 people.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. My closet is arranged by hue, saturation, and luminosity.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I\'m a visual artist.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. I\'m a Minnesota native.',
        'Hello! I\'m Zac. The servers that host this website are 100% wind powered.'
        ];
    textArray.shuffle();

    $('#text-content').loadText( textArray, 6000 ); // ( array, interval )
});

// custom jquery plugin loadText()
$.fn.loadText = function( textArray, interval ) {
    return this.each( function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        obj.fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
            obj.empty().html( random_array( textArray ) );
            obj.fadeIn( 'slow' );
        });
        timeOut = setTimeout( function(){ obj.loadText( textArray, interval )}, interval );
        // reload random text (if not animated) -- entirely optional, can be removed, along with the reload link above (<a href="javascript:;" id="text-reload"><em>randomize</em></a>)
        $("#text-reload").click( function(){
            if( !obj.is(':animated') ) { clearTimeout( timeOut ); obj.loadText( textArray, interval );} // animation check prevents "too much recursion" error in jQuery
        });
    });
}
//public function
function random_array( aArray ) {
    var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * aArray.length + aArray.length );
    var randArray = aArray[ rand - aArray.length ];
    return randArray;
}
```

Comment: It's my attempt at getting the array to shuffle :) Not working, though. It kills the script.

Comment: Can someone with sufficient privileges please edit this post to be tagged JavaScript and not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built in shuffle function in javascript, which is why textArray.shuffle() is causing your code to fail. You could achieve a shuffle by using the sort function. You just need to pass sort, a function that randomly returns a positive or negative number.

Here is code that should shuffle your array.

```
textArray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
```

This should result in the effect you want.

Comment: Varun, thanks for the quick answer! Also, sorry for categorizing the post in java, guess I wasn't paying attention. I placed the code you suggested below the array. Good news is that it doesn't kill the script, but it doesn't work yet :/

Comment: Are you sure you put this right after declaring textArray? I used firebug to run this code after you declare the array in random.js, and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, here's the code I'm using now.

`$(document).ready( function() {
    var textArray = [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        '10',
  '11',
  '12'
  ];
 
 textArray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})`

Answer (score 0):

You can write an array shuffle.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/RPw9X/

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var s = [];
    while (this.length) s.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1)[0]);
    while (s.length) this.push(s.pop());
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use a different approach:

```
​var RandomArray = function(myArray) {
  var
  currentArray = [],
  originalArray = myArray.slice(0);

  // Shuffle the array
  var shuffle = function() {
      var tmpArray = originalArray.slice(0);
      while(tmpArray.length) {
        var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpArray.length);
        currentArray.push(tmpArray.splice(idx, 1)[0]);
      }
  };

  // Get the next element
  this.next = function() {
    if(currentArray.length == 0) {
      shuffle();
    }
    return currentArray.shift();
  };
}​;

rnd = new RandomArray(a);
```

It does:

- Create a newly shuffle'd array everytime every `myArray.length` elements.
- Do not repeat elements, except for the chance the last element has.

You can integrate this in your script by modifying:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var textArray = [ ... ];
  rnd = new RandomArray(textArray);
  $('#text-content').loadText( rnd, 6000 );
});

$.fn.loadText = function( rnd, interval ) {
  ...
  obj.empty().html( rnd.next() );
  ...
  timeOut = setTimeout( function(){ obj.loadText( rnd, interval )}, interval );
  ...
  if( !obj.is(':animated') ) { clearTimeout( timeOut ); obj.loadText( rnd, interval );}
  ...
}
```

Drop `random_array`.

Comment: Hm. I think I have a syntax error, but I can't find it... http://www.zbettendorf.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/js/random.js Here's a link to the source script.

Comment: @Zac, sorry, I can't do nothing about if you keep modifying it :)